# Chown breaks in bound volumes with Docker user namespace remapping: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: linux, docker, container

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) for enabling user namespace remapping.

However, now inside of a container I can no longer change the ownership of a `-v` bounded volume.

I'm using Docker on Fedora with `docker-compose`. The volumes are bound like this:

```yml
service_name:
  volumes:
    - ./vol/service:/opt/service:Z
  # other config info removed...
```

I tried adding `cap_add`:

```yml
service_name:
  volumes:
    - ./vol/service:/opt/service:Z
  cap_add:
    - CHOWN
    - SETGID
    - SETUID
  # other config info removed...
```

That didn't help. The root user inside of the container cannot `chown` on the folder that's bound (in this example, `/opt/service`), or any of the contents inside of the folder, even when I ran `chmod go+rwx vol/service` on the host.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do two things to fix this problem:

1. I needed to remove the `:Z` on the volume binding
2. I needed to make sure that the permissions on the bound folder on the host started with the UID and GID found in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`, respectively. In other words, I had to run (on the host): `chown -R 100000:100000 vol/service`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).